# DataList Columns Distribution

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am programming using .NET aspx. In the asp:DataList component I want to distribute columns evenly, even in case not all columns are assigned an ItemTemplate.

E.g.

```
<asp:DataList id="test" runat="server" Width="90%" gridlines="None"
    RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
    RepeatColumns="4" HorizontalAlign="Left">
<ItemTemplate> ... </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

At runtime the array bound to the datalist only contains 2 elements. I still want the columns to be distributed evenly over the four spaces.

Comment: If use `Code Sample` button (the little button with '101 010'), your code will appear.  It also makes the code easier to read.

Comment: Please paste your full ItemTemplate contents

Answer (score 1):

If you are dedicated to using a DataList, there are two reasonable methods for accomplishing this.

**First, you can wrap your `ItemTemplate` in a `div` with a fixed width.**

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <div style="width: 250px;">
  ...
  </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

**Secondly, if your DataList must expand or contract to fit the viewer's screen, you can utilize jquery.**

We will be grabbing the computed client width of the datalist after page load and adjusting the columns to be distributed evenly.

```
<asp:DataList id="MyDataList" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Width="90%" gridlines="None"
    RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
    RepeatColumns="4" HorizontalAlign="Left">
  <ItemTemplate>  
    <div class="DataListItem">
    ....
    </div>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Two quick notes before we see the jquery

- ClientIDMode="Static" on the datalist
- Every datalist item will be wrapped in a div with class "DataListColumn"

In jquery, upon page load, you can get the computed datalist width as follows

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
    $(".DataListItem").width($("#MyDataList").width() / 4); // Set the column width    
});
```

With all of that said, you may want to just use a repeater so you can have more control over actual columns.